# How to migrate a .change function from jQuery to plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm not a JS expert but i think what i'm trying to do is pretty simple (at least in jQuery)

I've got 3 select

```
  <select id="faq" class="onchance_fill">...</select>
  <select id="pages" class="onchance_fill">...</select>
  <select id="faq" class="onchance_fill">...</select>
```

and an input (it's a tinyMCE one in advlink plugin)

```
<input type="text" onchange="selectByValue(this.form,'linklisthref',this.value);" value="" class="mceFocus" name="href" id="href" style="width: 260px;">
```

**I want that each time i change a value in one of the 3 select, that this value of the option, will be placed in the input.**

In Jquery, it would be something like :

```
$('.ajax_onchance_fill').change(function() {
        data = $('.ajax_onchance_fill').val();
        $('#href').text(data);
    });
```

But i can't use it. So what is the equivalent in plain Javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: You're making your life harder by moving away from jQuery - try asking "what's wrong with this jQuery?" before you opt to go down a route that is more labour intensive in terms of browser support.

Comment: have you tried $('.ajax_onchance_fill').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });  ?  in order to check that the change event is firing?

Comment: While I agree that jQuery is the bees knees, we aren't really sure why he can't use it, but he did state he can't...

Comment: @jesus.tesh - yeah, a bit vague.  I'm working with the presumption that if he began by attempting it in jQuery then he is able to use jQuery, he just didn't manage to get it working.

Comment: @Nathan - yeah, I am with you. I am not sure why anyone would put himself through having to NOT use jQuery! :)

Comment: I can't use jQuery, i want to but in that particular case, I can't. (Depandancies with TinyMCE) @Nathan @jesus.tesh :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you keep using Jquery as it speeds up this kind of thing but in pure JavaScript i think what you want looks something like this...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('onchance_fill');
  for(e in elements){
      elements[e].onchange = function(){
          document.getElementById('href').value = this.value;
     }       
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, it's not working (no error output), do i need to call the load() method ?

Comment: yeah you will, like in Jquery you might do the $(document).ready(), you need to call load after the dom has finished loading. You can use the onload="load()" on your body but that doesn't grantee that the dom is loaded like Jquery would

Comment: Nice, it's working :-) Thanks... anyway, pure JS... wow, i missed jQuery on that case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ajax_onchance_fill").onchange = function() { 
   getElementById('href').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
};
```

Though I am not sure exactly if it'll work since `getElementsByClassName` returns more than 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.ajax_onchance_fill').change(function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        $('#mytextboxid').val(data);
    });
```

Comment: He wants to get rid of the jquery ;-)

Comment: @Pendo - see comments on the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I realize this thread is well over 8 years old, so this answer isn't so much for the OP (who probably figured it out long ago) as it is for someone else who might be curious about this particular topic.

All that said, here's a relatively simple and reliable way you could pull it off in vanilla JS:

```
/**
 * Since we need to listen to all three ajax_onchance_fill elements,
 * we'll use event delegation.
 * 
 */

const targetLink = document.getElementById('href'); 

    document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

        if (!!Element.prototype.matches) { // Let's make sure that matches method is supported...

            if (e.target.matches('.ajax_onchance_fill')) {

                targetLink.textContent = e.target.value;

            }

        } else { // and if not, we'll just use classList.contains...

            if (e.target.classList.contains('ajax_onchance_fill')) {

                targetLink.textContent = e.target.value;

            }
        
        }   

    });
```